# Test does not compile: "the async keyword is missing from the function declaration"

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to get working tests in my project (src/subdir/subdir2/file.rs):

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_format_str() {
        let src = "a";
        let expect = "a";
        assert_eq!(expect, src);
    }
}
```

And get this error compiling:

```
error: the async keyword is missing from the function declaration
   --> src\domain\models\product.rs:185:11
    |
185 |     async fn test_format_str() {
    |           ^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which makes no sense to me since async is there.

My original plan was this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_format_str() {
        let src = "a";
        let expect = "a";
        assert_eq!(expect, src);
    }
}
```

Since all tests aren't async, but that gives the same error:

```
error: the async keyword is missing from the function declaration
   --> src\domain\models\product.rs:185:5
    |
185 |     fn test_format_str() {
    |     ^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm using tokio = { version = "0.2.22", features = ["full"]}, exporting macros from src/main.rs.

I tried use test::test; to get the std test macro but that gives an ambiguous import compilation error.

I checked out this post [Error in Rust unit test: "The async keyword is missing from the function declaration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600409/error-in-rust-unit-test-the-async-keyword-is-missing-from-the-function-declara) but it doesn't address my issue as far as I can tell, I need the macro export.

Full reproducable example.
Win10, rustc 1.46.0.
Just a main.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    Ok(())
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    async fn test_format_str() {
        let src = "a";
        let expect = "a";
        assert_eq!(expect, src);
    }
}
```

with a single dependency:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2.22", features = ["full"]}
```

Removing

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate tokio;
```

and using tokio macros as tokio:: ex. tokio::try_join! solves the immediate problem, although it would be nice to know why this happens.

Comment: Could you share a full minimal example, with all `use` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `tokio_macros`, versions 0.2.4 and 0.2.5. The following minimal example also fails to build:

```
use tokio::test;

#[test]
async fn it_works() {}
```

The underlying problem is with the code this test macro expands to. In the currently released version, it is roughly the following:

```
#[test]
fn it_works() {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new()
        .basic_scheduler()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .unwrap()
        .block_on(async { {} })
}
```

Note the `#[test]` attribute. It is intended to refer to the standard `test` attribute, i.e. to the ordinary test function marker, but, since `tokio::test` is in scope, it is invoked instead again - and, since the new function is not async, it throws an error.

The issue was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/commit/1cc016833569e2dbae3b0431b7c87d5e75ef5de6), where `test` is replaced with `::core::prelude::v1::test`, i.e. explicitly pulled in from `core`. But the corresponding change didn't make it yet into the released version, and I suspect this won't be fast, since this is technically a breaking change - bumping minimally supported Rust version.
For now, the only workaround seems not to use wildcard imports with `tokio`, either explicitly or through `macro_use`, and `use` anything you need explicitly instead.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is as close to a solution as we are going to get.